# Why do I get an error with .Click() Event for an Asp:LinkButton in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, click, linkbutton, asplinkbutton

I am attempting to fire the click() event when a button is clicked.

This currently works for me in IE however I receive the following error in firefox:

"link.click is not a function"

I have been trawling google regarding this and found out the .click event is not supported in all versions of firefox.

Is anyone able to provide an alternative? Code below:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonNext" runat="server" CssClass="RemoveLinkStyle" TabIndex="1"></asp:LinkButton>
<table id="tblButtonNext" runat="server" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pwbtn" onclick="ButtonClick(ButtonNext);" TabIndex="1" onmouseout="this.className='pwbtn';" onmouseover="this.className='pwbtnh';">
<tr>
    <td class="a1"></td>
    <td class="a2">
        <%= this.resourceManager.GetString("nextstep") %>
    </td>
    <td class="a3"></td>
    <td class="spacer"></td>
</tr>
</table>

function ExecuteLink(linkID)
{
    var link = document.getElementById(linkID);
    link.click();
}

function ButtonClick(linkID)
{
    PreNavigationScript();
    CallShowBlocker();
    ExecuteLink(linkID); 
}
```

Comment: what a mess. pls format your code block

Comment: but the `onclick` is on the `table` rather than on the `LinkButton`. What is it REALLY that you want to do?

Comment: @Bazzz table click raises button click, which is probably a postback event assigned in the code behind. it's a bit dodgy =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this. The `click` event exposed by jQuery is designed to be cross browser compatible and you'll likely find it works more consistently than what you're currently using.

Your method will then become:

```
 function ExecuteLink(linkID)
{
   $("#" + linkID).click();
}
```

(You probably want to check whether $(linkID) returns an element also)

Comment: is it `$("#" + linkID)` rather?

Comment: This is what I needed, thank you! I also ran into another problem where by I had to pass my button click into a Ajax function to register the postback to the button but still using your above code to get the button click event.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `CausesValidation="False"` will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jQuery then your alternative is pretty hacky mouse event for firefox, e.g.

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, 
false, false, false, 0, null); 
AnchorFieldObj.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

as per [mozilla.dev.tech.dom](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.dom/browse_thread/thread/78e15cb742b88adf)

**However**, another alternative is to call the function handling your button click event. View Source and check what it is, it'll be something like `__doPostback('ButtonNext',...);` and call it in your ExecuteLink() funct.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the click()-Method of Jquery too, but the event was never triggered.

You can access the generated javascript Method of the Linkbutton directly:

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContentPlaceholder$MyLinkButtonId','');
```

The ASP-Linkbutton is rendered to a input field and an anchor in the final HTML-Code. The first parameter is the (client-)name of this inputfield.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code snippet in your .master page or any other appropiate page just before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
var theform;
if (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("microsoft") > -1) {
theform = document.aspnetForm;
}
else {
theform = document.forms["aspnetForm"];
}
theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget.split("$").join(":");
theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
theform.submit();
}
// -->
</script>
```

Replace 'aspnetForm' with your own.